# Crawlers that work with infinite scroll pages

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-crawler, infinite-scroll

I'm looking for a a crawler app that scans the javascript of the page for AJAX requests and looks for functions that execute AJAX calls thus getting the whole content from beginning to end.

I would write something myself but I'm really busy with work right now and thought maybe someone already made a crawler like this.

Is there?

Comment: Busy? Time management. Always works. You should try it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but if there is a crawler like this I rather know because it wont be the first time I waste a weekend coding tools that already existed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as what you are asking for as it would be way too specific to one particular site - there is no generic way for a crawler to make ajax generated content appear.

Google has implemented some conventions for making ajax generated pages crawlable if the web site is willing to cooperate.  You can read about them here: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174992

Comment: Thanks, I guess the site is crawler-friendly since its content is very prominent in search engines